# Can we modify geth that not store any blockchain data?

Tags: go-ethereum, chaindata

Is it possible to run a modified geth that just logs data of the new block and doesn't store any blockchain data in database?

Comment: Yes, it should be possible. The problem is that you won't be sure what is the last valid block.

Comment: @Ismael Where or which function should I start to remove the database storage functionality?

Comment: Probably the best approach is to catch the blocks at the p2p level before they propagate. You have to catch the blocks before Process in https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/state_processor.go.